# Why didn't Mark Watney start digging downward?

Tags: the-martian

I've watched [The Martian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Martian_(film)) and I've read the book, yet I still don't understand one thing.

**If he ran out of horizontal space for crops, why didn't Mark Watney start digging downward?**

In the book he used part of the Hab's floor canvas to make a "mars tent" for sleeping and working (which was dropped completely from original release and present as pretty big 100% Earth-made tent in directors cut), so he could make a "hatch" without losing the Hab completely. Digging downward through soil, rocks, etc would be a problem at first, but Mark is creative, he could make some kind of pickaxe. In a few month he would have an underground area for planting more potatoes (plus in the book he had peas and corn, yet he chose potatoes only... for some reason), which would give him way better chances of survival till Ares 4 (and a stronger hit, when the Hab actually blew up).

So, why didn't he dig?

P.S.: I'm not asking this on scientific communities of Stack Exchange, because, frankly, considering Martian radiation, very weak sunlight and pretty bad (although not completely unusable) soil, the book/movie is not really a hard science... Not hard enough, at least.

Comment: Why potatoes and not peas and/or corn?  The biggest difference I can see between the food production is that peas and corn require pollination, tuber growth does not.  Possibly also the amount of food that could be produced from original seed stock might factor in.  You want more potatoes, you just mound more dirt to cover more of the stem. I assume they have artificial lighting in the hab, that could be focused on plants, and scientists have generally concurred that growing food, as depicted, is not unrealistic.

Comment: I'm also not sure why you deem growing food, in general, to be unrealistic because of Martian sunlight, but growing food underground to be a possibility.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet I deem unrealistic growing anything (including potatoes) in his conditions (dim electric lights instead of sunlight and martian dust with human manure, processed by Earth bacteria, instead of proper soil). But since he actually can (somehow) grow potatoes in these conditions, why not make a basement for them?

Comment: "Not ideal" <> "unrealistic"

Comment: @MrScapegrace: Actual botanists have taken a look at the crop thing and have said that it's feasible. We have actually grown plants using sterile soil mixed with manure (alas not human). So that part is hard science. The consensus is that the only part that's not hard science is the weather in the beginning. The rest that you dismiss as not hard science have been verified as hard science by actual scientists involved in the particular fields

Comment: Does *biological materials* mean ?

Comment: "yet he chose potatoes only... for some reason". Perhaps it's because potatoes have a greater calorie yield per acre than corn (17 to 12  roughly) and an even greater margin against peas. Space was extremely limited, and he'd definitely want the most bang for his buck here. Corn could also need more sun (not sure on this one)

Comment: Have just been reading this book. He indeed says he chooses potatoes because they have the highest calorie content. He already has all the vitamins and protein he needs, he only needs calories. While variety might have been nice, it would have limited the days he would be able to live.

Comment: FYI to all - I also just read, researching an answer to a vegetarian dietary question, that potatoes have a very complete essential amino acid profile.

Comment: He also picked potatoes because he had a lot of them (relatively speaking) and it is possible to chop them up into pieces and have the pieces grow into new potato plants.

Comment: Something you need to understand about growing plants is how they start to grow in the first place. Most plants start with a germinated seed. You can start a potato using a part of the potato itself called the "eye". If you've ever seen a potato which sits around for a long time, it will start consuming itself and start growing a new plant out of the eye. You cannot do this with a pea or a kernel of corn. It is *really* easy to do with potatoes. He used potatoes not only for the caloric bit mentioned, but due to how potatoes are able to grow in the first place.

Comment: Something I haven't seen mentioned here yet, as a slight addition to already complete answers: Why would Watney not use a pickaxe? Watney was already starved for nutrition, and swinging a pickaxe all day would only lead to him needing more nutrition. He simply could not spare the extra effort _now_ for the return on harvest _in the future_, as he would not have enough food to make it to that future harvest. Plus, while physically fit, that doesn't mean he's equipped for extremely hard labor. He's a scientist, not a miner.

Comment: I'm afraid the problem of running out of horizontal space for crops *isn't mentioned in the film at all*, which makes your entire question pretty much completely moot.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Because he would need to make an airtight seal between the walls of the Hab and the ground.

What is shown in the movie is that the Hab is a prefabricated 'tent', and Mark shifts a significant amount of Martian rock dust into that space through the airlock and makes soil that can support a potato by adding "biological materials" and water.

In this scenario he doesn't have to make this airtight, it is already.  To dig down into the ground he would have to make a reliable seal between the Hab materials and dusty rocky ground, which would be extremely hard.

I'm also not entirely convinced that the extra area that he might be able to generate would be easy or even sustainable.  For this to be worthwhile he would have to dig down and make a cave that extends beyond the border of the Hab - with all the physical work removing the material out of the Hab via an airlock, which would be backbreaking.  Then he'd have to provide enough lighting and water.  He has a limited amount of hydrazine to make water - which would be absorbed not only into his new planting soil, but also (uselessly) into the walls and roof of his cave.

His air appears to be a relatively replenishable resource from the the 'airmaker'/oxygenator that the story mentions, which is presumably solar powered.  The water is not infinitely replenishable, and every time he goes outside to get rid of a bag of rock from his mining he dumps 1 airlock full of water vapor.

Comment: As I mentioned in a question, in the book he did an airtight seal after cutting Hab floor for "martian tent". He was using superglue sparringly and he had enough spare hub canvas (at first at least), so I don't think that making a "sock" and glueing it to layer of soil between Hub and "basement" wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: No, he never creates a seal between Hab material and dirt in the book.

Comment: @sirjonsnow .... I agree, it seems implausible to me that you could create a seal with a small amount of superglue.  You might create one with almost literally gallons of it, but even then if the rock had any cracks you would have a slow (but perhaps manageable) leak.

Comment: @iandotkelly And not even the ISS is completely airtight (though in that case they know the approximate amount of loss and take it into account when determining how much oxygen/etc. to keep in reserve).

Comment: Aside from air considerations etc, digging and swinging a pick-axe consumes a massive amount of calories. Didn't read the book: was it a savings over digging to scrape/gather the regolith?

Comment: @MrScapegrace: I have the book here. Can you point me to where he actually punctured the hab canvas and glued it to the ground? I can't seem to find it. I have an e-book so page numbers would be useless but at least tell me which chapter or before/after what event? From what I've read the only thing he did was glue hab canvas to hab canvas to seal tha hab back. Remember: the hab is a balloon.

Comment: @slebetman I'm guessing that he's thinking of when Mark makes the "Bedroom", cutting chunks out of the hab, and gluing the top to the "floor".  Not realizing that the "floor" was the floor of the hab, rather than the surface of Mars.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56280/discussion-between-aron-and-iandotkelly).

Comment: @MrScapegrace go outside and try to glue a piece of canvas to some dirt to form an airtight seal and let me know how that works out for you...

Answer (score 31):

The question on the potatoes was directly addressed in the book.  They gave the most calories per area of farm land.

Couple other points where you appear to have miss interpreted/remembered some details.  The hab is not sealed to the ground.  When they got there they laid out the floor materials, staked them down, attached the canvas for the sides and top, and hooked up the other components.  It is a free standing tent with a semi rigid floor and lots of accessories to keep the people in it alive and comfortable.

When Mark made his bedroom/working tent, he took a portion of the canvas from the hab top & sides, and the floors of the emergency tents from the rovers, and remanufactured things to get a larger single tent in place of the two smaller ones.  There were several references in the book to the Hab ceiling being lower on one side after this because of the missing canvas.

Also the hab was providing more than just atmosphere containment for the farm.  It also had light and heat.  I am pretty sure there was a line in the book about the hab using UV lights for the health of the crew, which made them good grow lights for the plants.  Trying to replicate any of those conditions outside of the controlled environment of the hab would have been enormously more difficult, both in terms of technical feasibility, and the level of effort expended.

Keep in mind that his primary issue was calorie deficiency.  He had plenty of vitamins and supplements to last for years if he could find enough calories to keep his body running.  Anything that involved additional physical exertion, without directly and immediately contributing to his survivability, would have made the problem worse.

Comment: I seem to recall him also having some kind of glue for the seams. But that wouldn't help much with the martian soil.

Comment: Correct.  He had a glue for sealing the canvas material to itself, and/or patching his suit.